# Alert confirmed in Firefox but nothing happens after

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, cucumber, watir

Have a test that selects a radio button, and clicks a Delete button triggering a modal dialog/alert box pop up.

I'm using Cucumber so here's how the step works:

```
When /^i confirm the alert$/ do 
      Watir::Wait.until(timeout: 10) {@browser.alert.exists?}
      puts "i see the alert"
      @browser.alert.ok 
end
```

I put in that lazy debug step because I was thinking this may be a browser/driver issue.

I've had this work in Chrome but it's not an option for the certain environment I'm in for this particular script.

Firefox is my only option and here is what happens:

- "i see the alert" is returned
- the dialog is confirmed on

then I receive **unable to locate alert (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)**

I'm on Firefox 45 ESR / Selenium Webdriver 3.0.5

Not sure if it's a Firefox/Selenium compatibility issue or not?

The application doesn't do anything after the **OK** button is clicked on the alert

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML/js that reproduces the issue?  Does the same issue exist if you upgrade FF and use the most recent `geckodriver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix! And it was quite simple. I simply needed to send the Alert handling to Selenium instead of Watir.

Instead of calling the **Watir::Alert** class:

```
@browser.alert.ok
```

I just needed to let Selenium handle it. This is working in both FF and Chrome now:

```
And(/^the user confirms the alert via selenium$/) do
    popup = @browser.driver.switch_to.alert
    popup.accept
end
```

Comment: You are accessing selenium code, but you don't have to because alert.ok is actually accessing that code with additional checking. Look the code `  def ok
      wait_for_exists
      @alert.accept
      @browser.after_hooks.run
    end`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using Watir 6.2.1; there was a bug fix we just released that might fix this issue for you.

Comment: Just updated my 6.1.0 watir gem. No luck there. It's just odd. The confirm alert action works for Chrome and displays the correct message in my application but it seems that in FF the confirm action isn't taking.

Comment: No it somewhat makes sense, Firefox handles alerts slightly differently than Chrome. Please set `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info` in your code and post a gist of the output.

Comment: @partydog actually the fix was done in 6.2.1 not in 6.1.0, yes it works in chrome but not in Firefox . Please update to 6.2.1 and then check.

Comment: See above comment @Gopal. I updated my watir from 6.1 to 6.2.1 and still saw the issue in FF. Found a fix though (posted below).